# Help prove a claim about tangent plane

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a differentiable function $f(x):\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ and the hyperplane $H=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^{n+1}  ~ | \quad a^Tx-y=a^Tx_0-f(x_0)\}$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ which goes through the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ living on the graph of $f$.  Show that if the $\text{epi} f$ is entirely contained in one closed halfspace of $H$, then $H$ must be the tangent plane of $f$ at $x_0$ i.e., $H=\{(x,y) ~|\quad y=f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)^T (x-x_0)  \}$?

Comment: It must be **a** tangent plane, there may be many. For example, if $f(x) = |x|$ then any of $x \mapsto (x, \alpha x)$, with $|\alpha| \le 1$ are tangent planes to the epigraph at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks I fixed this.

Comment: How do you define tangent place if not the above?

Comment: I have edited your question, people usually take a geometric approach as tangent plane, Seemingly you took analytical version of tangent plane as definition. BTW  What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume $$\text{epi} (f)  \subseteq H^+ = \{ (x,y)~ | \quad y\ge f(x_0) + a^T (x - x_0)  ~ \forall x \in  R^n   \}$$
 Clearly  $\text{graph} (f) \subseteq \text{epi} (f) \subseteq  H^+ $ thus $$f(x)\ge f(x_0) + a^T (x - x_0)  ~~ \forall x \in  R^n   $$ which is saying that the function $g(x ) = f(x) - f(x_0) - a^T (x - x_0)$ attains its global minimum point at $ x=x_0 $ which implies $\nabla g(x_0) = 0$ so $\nabla f(x_0) = a.$ Hence,
$$H = \{ (x,y)~ | \quad y = f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) (x - x_0)  ~ \forall x \in  R^n   \}$$